# How can I add a Placeholder in a React CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have read the documentation of ckeditor regarding the React Context , but I couldn't find how to make a Placeholder on the CKEditor.

This is the link to the react ckeditor  [react ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html)

This is the sample code :

```
<CKEditor
    onInit={editor => {
        // Insert the toolbar before the editable area.
        editor.ui.view.editable.element.parentElement.insertBefore(
        editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
        editor.ui.view.editable.element);}}
        name={this.state.body}
        onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
        editor={DecoupledEditor}
        data={this.state.body}
        />
```

Comment: See https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/479

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<CKEditor 
  config={{placeholder: "Placeholder text..."}} 
  ... 
  />
```

Works for me

Comment: Is there any way for me to add line breaks to placeholders? I've tried multiple ways, but Im not able to add line breaks!